# c# ASP.Net Core and Linq: aggregate functions MIN and MAX

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Visual Studio 2019; ASP.Net Core 2.1

I have a DB system that has a table of events that happen on various machines.

```
// pseudo code
eventLog (
    id int primary key not null,
    eventType varchar(16) not null,
    machineName varchar(64) not null,
    loggedInUser varchar(16) not null,
    eventDate datetime not null,
)
```

I want to retrieve the earliest and most recent event dates for a particular machine.  In SSMS I can get the info I want with:

```
SELECT
       MIN([eventDate]),
       MAX([eventDate])
FROM eventLog
WHERE UPPER(machineName) LIKE 'MY-MACHINENAME%';
```

In a sample run I get min/max values of:

```
2015-08-17 10:31:47.000 / 2019-05-02 12:54:20.000
```

Note: `machineName` can be either a "simple" string like "mypc" or an FQDN ("mypc.company.com").  I split out the first "dotted" segment of the possible FQDN and compare that to the `myMachine` variable that has already had any dotted portions removed.

In C# I am aware that there are `Aggregate` methods but I am having a hard time following the docs and examples I have found and translating them into actual practice.  I have so far:

```
public class VisibleRange {
    public DateTime start { get; set; }
    public DateTime end { get; set; }
}

...

var ctx = userTrackingContext.EventLog;

usertrackingRange = (
    from eventLog in userTrackingContext.EventLog
    where eventLog.Machine.ToUpper().Split(
        '.',
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
    )[0].Trim().Equals(myMachine)
    select eventLog.Date
).Select(range => new VisibleRange {
    start = ctx.Min(a => a.Date),
    end = ctx.Max(a => a.Date)
}).First();
```

This runs but is not giving me useful results for the Min value.  That is off by about 11 years.

```
8/2/2004 8:05:27 PM  /  5/2/2019 12:00:00 AM
```

How do I convert the SSMS query into a LINQ query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like:-

```
        var range = new VisibleRange() { };

        var matched = userTrackingContext.EventLog.Where(a => a.MachineName.StartsWith(myMachine));

        if(matched != null)
        {
            range.start = matched.Min(a => a.EventDate);
            range.end = matched.Max(a => a.EventDate);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following LINQ query

```
usertrackingRange = (
from eventLog in userTrackingContext.EventLog
where eventLog.Machine.ToUpper().Split(
    '.',
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
)[0].Trim().Equals(myMachine)
select eventLog.Date
).Select(range => new VisibleRange {
   start = ctx.OrderByAscending(a => a.Date).First(),
   end = ctx.OrderByDescending(a => a.Date).First()
}).First();
```

Comment: In the `ctx.OrderBy...` lines I am told that I cannot convert from the type of `ctx` to `DateTime`.  Can't see a way to coerce that.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick smoke test and your selects work for me. Why are you not calling range.Min and range.Max to get the results from your filtered data set?

```
var now = DateTime.Now;

var nums = new List<Num>
{
    new Num { Min = now, Max = now.AddDays(1) },
    new Num { Min = now.AddDays(10), Max = now.AddDays(50) },
    new Num { Min = now.AddDays(51), Max = now.AddDays(100) },
};

var minMaxNum = nums.Select(num => new Num
{
    Min = nums.Min(_ => _.Min),
    Max = nums.Max(_ => _.Max),
}).First();
```